# Is $\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}=\left\{\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asking myself if $\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}=\left\{\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Elements of $\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$ are $0,1,2$-valued configurations on the 2d-lattice.

**Edit**

Sorry, I have to make my question more clear.

The background is the following:

Let $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$. And $T\colon X\to X$.

Now consider $Y\subset\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}}$,
$$
Y:=\left\{(x,Tx,T^2x,\ldots): x\in X\right\}.
$$

Now consider the homeomorphism $f\colon Y\to X, (x,Tx,T^2x,...)\mapsto x$.

Is this a right form to write this? I mean that in the sense of a time-space diagram, i.e. that $x$ is a 0,1,2-configuration on the x-axis... $Tx$ is the 0,1,2-configuration standing in the "row" above the x-axis and so on.

Or how can I write $Y$ correctly?

Comment: Certainly with the outer curly braces it's false, perhaps you meant to use parentheses?

Comment: You mean $(\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}})^{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Comment: What's currently written is the set of functions from the integers into a one element set.

Comment: What is a "configuration" here? I find it odd that you are using the term "lattice" here, so I fear you are talking about something other than just functions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Lattice is a common term for this set of points, and it is reflected in the mathematical usage where lattice refers to a discrete subgroup of a Lie group.

Comment: And yes, he means $(\{0,1,2\}^{\mathbb{Z}})^{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I am well aware if the alternate meaning of lattice, but that doesn't make clear what he means by "configuration." And determining on your own what the OP means is wrong - he might have been given a trick homework question, and $\{\}$ was what he meant.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : I was answering the OP's query regarding the comment of Matt Samuel. Also, "wrong" is a strong word here. In this situation I thought the OP had a real mathematical question to ask, and suspected that his notation was just bad.

Comment: Sorry. "And yes..." was right after your reply to me, in which I requested clarification of the question, and so I assumed "he" was OP.  @LeeMosher Always dangerous to use pronouns in linear chat.

Comment: @Thomas: In linear algebra too. At least that's what she said. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. But your intentions are probably correct.

1. $\{x\}$ is a set with a single element. Therefore $\{x\}^\Bbb Z$ is the set of all functions from $\Bbb Z$ into that singleton, and there is only one function like that: $f(k)=x$ for all $k$.
2. If, however, you mean $\left(\{0,1,2\}^\Bbb Z\right)^\Bbb Z$, then this is not equal to, but isomorphic to. You get that the elements of this sets are functions from $\Bbb Z$ into the set of functions from $\Bbb Z$ into $\{0,1,2\}$. So $f(k)=g$ for some $g\colon\Bbb Z\to\{0,1,2\}$.

   Using Currying we can define a canonical bijection, $F(f)\colon\Bbb Z^2\to\{0,1,2\}$ is defined as $F(f)(n,k)=f(n)(k)$.

So to your question, no. But if you replace $\{\}$ by $()$ and equality by isomorphism, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Isomorphic?  As groups?  Where $\{0,1,2\}$ has addition mod 3?  OK.

Comment: Isomorphic as whatever structure that bijection preserves. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's not really correct to put an equal sign there. What would make more sense is to construct a bijection. Elements of $\{0,1,2\}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$ are functions $f : \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \{0,1,2\}$. Elements of $(\{0,1,2\}^\mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{Z}}$ are functions $g : \mathbb{Z} \to \{0,1,2\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$. The bijection is this: $f \leftrightarrow g$ if and only if, for all $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $f(m,n) = g(n)(m)$.

**Added to answer the OP's additional question:** Yes, this bijection is a homeomorphism with respect to product topologies, assuming of course the discrete topology on $\{0,1,2\}$. In fact, both sets are homeomorphic to the Cantor set, although that is not of course enough to conclude that the bijection itself gives the homeomorphism. However, it is not too hard to prove that the bijection in one direction is continuous, and knowing that both spaces are compact and Hausdorff is then enough to conclude that it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: By 30 seconds, or so. :-) (Also $\{\}$ is not correct there. But rather $()$ as you wrote in your answer.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila - Darn!

Comment: Is this bijection a homeomorphism?

Comment: I homemeomorphism of what? There is no topology here. @math12

Comment: Produt topology

Comment: You'd first have to come up with an exponential topology - $A^B$ if $A,B$ are sets, what topology do you want on $A^B$? Here, as far as anything *you've* said, these are discrete sets, so any bijection is a homeomorphism. If you want to give these spaces topologies, that should definitely be in your question. @math12

Comment: And, by the way, you have completely failed to answer *any* questions asked above to clarify your question. @math12

Comment: @ThomasAndrews there is a natural topology on this set and it isn't discrete.

Comment: @math12: I've added an answer to your question about homeomorphism.

Comment: @MattSamuel That doesn't excuse him from making the definition clear. He calls $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ a lattice, so maybe he also wants the lattice topology on that set. OPs terminology has been far from precise or helpful.